# Como contar registro , con condiciones multiples

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en MySQL, tengo una tabla que contiene lo siguiente:

1. tabla: `id,   ano,   m1,  m2,  m3,  m4,   m5,  m6,  m7`
2. datos:  `10,  2016,  I,   P,   L,   I,    L,   P,   I`

O sea, lo que quiero lograr es que me cuente  cuando sea específicamente el `ano` y el `id`, es decir el ejemplo sólo tiene de dato el `ano` `2016` y en el siguiente ejemplo de consulta la hago al `ano` `2015` y me cuenta de todos modos la `I` en la tabla calf

#### consulta que realizo:

```sql
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS r
FROM `calf` 
WHERE ano='2015' AND id='10' AND m1='I' OR m2='I' OR m3='I' OR m4='I' OR m5='I' OR m6='I' OR m7='I'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la condición que estás usando. El select se puede interpretar como:

```sql
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS r 
FROM `calf` 
WHERE 
    (ano ='2015' AND id ='10' AND m1 ='I')
    OR m2 ='I' 
    OR m3 ='I' 
    OR m4 ='I' 
    OR m5 ='I' 
    OR m6 ='I' 
    OR m7 ='I'
```

Es decir, con que se cumpla cualquiera de las condiciones de los campos `m`, basta para que selecciones el registro.

En cambio, agrupando de esta forma lo podrás solucionar:

```sql
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS r 
FROM `calf` 
WHERE 
    ano ='2015' AND id ='10'
    AND (
       m1 ='I' OR m2 = 'I' OR m3 = 'I' 
       OR m4 = 'I' OR m5 = 'I' OR m6 = 'I' OR m7 = 'I'
    )
```

---

**Sumar las `I` que aparecen por columna, siempre que cumpla `ano` y `id`:**

```sql
SELECT 
    sum( m1 = 'I' ) as totalm1,
    sum( m2 = 'I' ) as totalm2,
    sum( m3 = 'I' ) as totalm3,
    sum( m4 = 'I' ) as totalm4,
    sum( m5 = 'I' ) as totalm5,
    sum( m6 = 'I' ) as totalm6,
    sum( m7 = 'I' ) as totalm7


FROM `calf`

WHERE 
    ano ='2015' AND id ='10'
```

Comment: Hola @Mariano , muchas gracias por la respuesta me sirvio para otra solucion que necesitaba, pero lo que realimente deseo sacar como resultado de esta consulta es la cantidad en que parece "I"  con esas condiciones y contarlo entre las diferentes columnas

Comment: Excelente hermano @Mariano esa medida me funciono!